# Spring Boot - Disable default login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently working on a small Project.
I want to use keycloak as authorization server and my applicationn as spring gateway and oauth2 client.

**Here is the Problem:**

When entering a endpoint, i get redirected to the keycloak login page witch is fine.
But whenever i enter the endpoint "localhost:9090/login" i get to the default oauth2 login page:
[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U46Ge.png)

Since i use oauth2 client dependency and using `ServerHttpSecurity` instead of `HttpSecurity`, i cannot use:

```java
httpSecurity
        .oauth2Login()
        .loginPage("/redirect");
```

---

**Here is my current configration:**

If you have Questions, i pushed the demo into this [github repo](https://github.com/matkollin/keycloak-gateway-demo)

**Gateway pom.xml**

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>at.matkollin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Gateway application.yaml:**

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak-spring-gateway-client:
            provider: my-keycloak-provider
            scope: openid
            client-id: spring-gateway-client
            client-secret: xxxxxxxxxx
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/keycloak"
        provider:
          my-keycloak-provider:
            issuer-uri: http://172.31.0.2:8080/realms/Demo
            token-uri: http://172.31.0.2:8080/auth/realms/Demo/protocol/openid-connect/token
            authorization-uri: http://172.31.0.2:8080/auth/realms/Demo/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            userinfo-uri: http://172.31.0.2:8080/auth/realms/Demo/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username

server:
  port: 9090

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

**Security Config:**

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                        .authorizeExchange()
                        .pathMatchers("/actuator/**", "/")
                        .permitAll()
                        .and()
                        .authorizeExchange()
                        .anyExchange()
                        .authenticated()
                        .and()
                        .oauth2Login();

        return http.build();
    }
```

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it with following configuration

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[0]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[1]=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Second line is to disable actuator security

Comment: Doens't seem to work. I still get the default login page. I also tried:
```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Can you post your package structure for `Application` class and `SecurityConfig` class

Comment: sure, i pasted it in the main thread

Comment: Also pushed the demo into github for further questions: https://github.com/matkollin/keycloak-gateway-demo

Comment: Are you sure your "gateway" is intended to be an OAuth2 **client** and not a **resource-server**?

Comment: The gateway should only check for auth and push anything else thru the other services. A Resource server should be a protected service documented by spring [here](https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/16/securing-services-with-spring-cloud-gateway), so yes, it's meant to be like that

Comment: I'm surprised with this article: the gateway being a proxy for all resources, I'd concider it a resource-server. The client on the first figure being the "browser". Also I prefer to give the responsibility of Authorization handeling to the client rather than a gateway: what if you try to add a native mobile app in addition to a SPA in a browser?

Comment: @MatKollin more details why I would not configure an API gateway as an OAuth2 client: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73743848/619830 I'd rather have "real" **clients** (those with the UI code) handle user login (with the help of client-side OAuth2 library), **gateway** just forward authorization header and deal with access control in **resource-servers** (micro-services)

Comment: I sadly agree, using the spring gateway and  oauth2 client seems to have many problems together