# Spring OAuth2 - JWT token working on server but not on localhost?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am seeing that `myapp` is able to process the OAuth2 JWT token properly on the server, but it is giving token conversion error on localhost.

**My Flow is as below -**

**On Server**, the `myapp` is behind our **custom** `api-gateway`

1. **Getting Access Token** - Through postman, I hit  api-gateway token endpoint which in turn calls the authserver token endpoint. And I get OAuth JWT Token as response.

So, to summarize, postman
**request:** --(creds)--> api-gateway --(samecreds) --> auth-server
**response:** jwt token <-- (same jwt)-- api-gateway <--(jwt)-- auth-server

2. **Next, I hit `myapp` endpoint** - Again through postman, I hit api-gateway endpoints, which in turn hits the corresponding `myapp` endpoints. And I get the required response. For this request, before hitting the api-gateway, I set the header `Authorization: Bearer JWT from step1`

As the `myapp` developer, i know that the api-gateway is re-sending the JWT token to `myapp` using the same header mechanism i.e `Authorization: Bearer JWT from step1`. From the logs, i see this is the same value that I provided in postman when hitting the `api-gateway`

So,  postman request: --(jwt)--> api-gateway --(same jwt)--> `myapp`
and response is some data, which is trivial for this discussion.

The decoded JWT Payload is as below:

```
{
  "app-userId": "c54a-4140-9fa0-0f39",
  "user_name": "abc@xyz.com",
  "scope": [
    "all"
  ],
  "exp": 1656929583,
  "authorities": [
    "app1_viewer",
    "app1_modifier",
    "app2_viewer",
    "app2_blog_creator],
  "client_id": "api-gw-client"
  ...
}
```

Plz note - `"client_id": "api-gw-client"` field in the above payload. So the auth-server is issuing the token to `api-gateway` client.

---

Now on mylocal dev env i.e `myapp` running on localhost - i am trying to achieve similar flow as on server.

On localhost, the myapp is NOT running behind api-gateway, but its hit directly

1. Getting Access Token - Through postman, I hit api-gateway (same server instance as in server flow above. i.e api-gateway/auth-server's are not running on localhost but are running on server)  token endpoint which in turn calls the authserver token endpoint. And I get OAuth JWT Token as response.

So, postman request: --(creds)--> api-gateway --(samecreds) --> auth-server
response: jwt token <-- (same jwt)-- api-gateway <--(jwt)-- auth-server

Yes, this token can be used in Server Flow Step 2 and it works. And the decoded JWT token payload is same as I posted earlier i.e

```
{
  "app-userId": "c54a-4140-9fa0-0f39",
  "user_name": "abc@xyz.com",
  "scope": [
    "all"
  ],
  "exp": 1656929583,
  "authorities": [
    "app1_viewer",
    "app1_modifier",
    "app2_viewer",
    "app2_blog_creator],
  "client_id": "api-gw-client"
  ...
}
```

Plz note again - `"client_id": "api-gw-client"` field in the above payload. So the auth-server is issuing the token to `api-gateway` client. I am not sure yet if this field is trivial or important.

2. Next, I hit **`myapp` localhost endpoint** - Again through postman, But I hit `myapp` endpoints directly (not through api-gateway running on localhost). And for this request, before hitting, I set the header `Authorization: Bearer JWT from step1`.

**BUT THIS TIME I GET ERROR:**

> p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request
> failed: error="invalid_token", error_description="Cannot convert
> access token to JSON"

I want to know what is causing this error. I don't think the `client_id: api-gw-client` is causing this. Anyhow, I created a signed jwt token with `client_id: myapp` and used it in request. But still I get same error.
The `key` I am using on localhost matches(corresponds) to the one that the auth-server is using to sign. I double checked. So its for sure not a `key` issue.

I need the localhost based setup working, so i can test my api's locally with out deploying to server(deploying to server is quite time consuming in my case). So this setup is quite important for me to meet my deadlines. Any answers/suggests are greatly appreciated.

---

**The Spring OAuth2 Libraries used in my project are as below -**

1. `org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:5.4.2`
2. `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2:2.1.3.RELEASE`

And the class which is giving error is: [OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-security-oauth/blob/main/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java) ([API Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.html))

Comment: And where isyour implementation?

Comment: @Toerktumlare - which specific implementation, can you say. If i can share I will definitely do so.

Comment: `I am seeing that myapp is able to process the OAuth2 JWT token properly on the server, but it is giving token conversion error on localhost.` you are describing your code, where is your code?

Comment: @Toerktumlare - Tx for your interest. I am using Spring-oauth libraries and the error is coming from these libs. I have edited the Q to and added these libs. I am not a spring oauth expert..  i am relied on sof for guidance.

Comment: please read my comment, you are describing your code, your libraries your usercase. But i dont see any implementation. Where is YOUR code. How do you think anyone can reproduce this without seeing what YOU have coded

Comment: Most of the heavy lifting is done by the Spring OAuth Libraries. They capture the incoming `JWT` token from `Authorization` header. Then, validate it against the signing key, check expiry, pull the claims and populate the `SecurityContext` with these claims/GrantedAuthorities. It is these libraries that are failing on localhost but succeeding on server.

Comment: I know how the libraries work, im still asking you for your implementation. How can any of us know that what you have implemented is correct unless you show us your implementation or provide a small working example? Good luck

Comment: @Toerktumlare - thanks for your suggestion. I am looking at the code. It's enterprise code.. if i can safely share any part of it.. i will do so.. plz understand the limitations i have w.r.t sharing the code.

Comment: Then share a small working example explaining your problem

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I won't answer your question (@Toerktumlare is right, your security configuration is missing) but will instead try to explain why I would not make the API gateway an OAuth2 client.

Simply put, the role of an API gateway is to be a black box for a system resources, which could make it seen as a resource-server, but it should, in my opinion, remain transparent to OAuth2 (and other authentication mechanisms). Keep things simple:

- **clients** (UI) handle user login (when needed)
- **resource-servers** control access to resources
- **gateway** (if any) should remain as transparent as possible, just offering a single entry-point for all resources.

In your scneario:

- how do you expect things to happen if you're asked to implement Multi Factor Authentication: in addition to login / password, require one of biometry, external app validation, Goolgle authenticator token or whatever? Do you really intend to implement all that in the gateway in addition to the authorization-server?
- if it always get `api-gw-client` as client ID, how can your authorization-server achieve client based processing (like checking requested scopes are legit for a client, or adding client authorities to the access-tokens)?
- what about multi-tenant scenarios (`R1` and `R2` resource-servers behind the gateway expect identities from different issuers, or `C1` and `C2` clients do not authenticate users against the same authorization-server)?
- what if some clients and resource-servers use something else than OAuth2?

Also, your client(s) must know what media-type is accepted and produced at each API endpoint (XML, JSON, PDF, multipart, etc.) and set `Content-type` and `Accept` headers accordingly. Why would it be different for `Authorization` header?

In my opinion, if you want to save time and energy, use your API gateway to proxy **your resource-servers only**. Leave authorization-server(s) appart. Same for external APIs you do not maintain but your client(s) need, if any (Tweeter feed, Google API, etc.).

[This is how I always configure my resource-servers](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken):

- `Authorization` header is missing or invalid (malformed, expired, wrong issuer, bad audience, etc.) => 401 (unauthorized) and not 302 (redirect to login)

  - in multi-tenant scenarios, why should resource-server bother figuring out which authorization-server to redirect to ?
  - What should be the meaning of a redirect for clients which are not running in a browser, like mobile apps?
- `Authorization` header is valid but associated claims fail to pass access-control (bad authorities or not the expected subject for instance) => 403 (forbidden)

Clients should know how to aquire required access-token(s) and how to set `Authorization` header when it sends a request (this is what you curently do with Postman). It can even intercept 401 to trigger user authentication and then retry failed resource access. Serious OAuth2 client-side librairies (like [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) for Angular) provide with such features.

With such clients, gateway can act as facade for your resource-servers (and authorization-server or external APIs if you like, but why?), forwarding `Authorization` header and completely ignoring users login.

Comment: thanks for your answer and suggestion. +1.  I am looking at the code. It's enterprise project.. so I have limitations w.r.t sharing the code here.. if i can safely share any part of it.. i will do so..